# Getting error as "Gradle sync failed"after installing offline gradle into Android studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I'm installing `Android Studio` I have slow bandwidth so I decided to install it as offline. So I tried to install it offline so first I downloaded `Gradle` zip file. So I went to `File->Settings->Gradle` and into `global variable` I tick marked as it `OFFLINE` and provided a location where I've kept the zip file into folder. after clicking okay and restarted Android studio. again I clicked `Gradle sync` but still getting the same error.

> Gradle sync failed

I'm using Android studio the latest version and latest version of Gradle.

Comment: You mean i just need to install `gradle` as an online mode?

Comment: Okay let me try that once after `turn ON` internet connection.. and yes i see many times after installing Gradle, it takes some `jar files` .. from internet.

Comment: You can try to open Android Studio with administrator privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle would  be used by Android Studio to retrieve dependencies via sync for the installation and if you turn Gradle to offline mode it wouldn't be able to access dependencies from the web repositories. And because you don't have the dependencies available on your computer the sync fails during installation of Android Studio.

Developer tools such as Ivy, Maven and Gradle work this way to manage libraries/dependencies. Companies store the libraries at web accessible locations called repositories and people install these tools ( i.e. Gradle) with their software (e.g. Android Studio) for developers so that they can easily retrieve the dependencies